# Does changing the ini file stop you from getting achievements?

Tags: pc, achievements, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I started playing *Skyrim* and got the 'Unbound' achievement.

I was having a couple of performance issues, so I exited and tweaked the `SkyrimPrefs.ini` file, but now I've just completed Bleak Falls Barrow and I haven't received the achievement.

I did the FOV change in the console also, but immediately left the game (without saving), so I can't see that having affected it.  (Or could it?)

Any idea if changing the `.ini` could break the achievements?

Maybe its because I edited the one in 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\skyrim\Skyrim`, and not 
`C:\Users\<username>\Documents\My Games\Skyrim` ?

Comment: Are you talking about the Golden Claw quest? If so, that's not the quest that triggers the achievement; there's a main story quest later.

Comment: @DoozerBlake this is not an *exact* duplicate as the main focus of this is about editing files outside of the game, not using commands within it.

Comment: @NickT Gotcha. Unfamiliar with the PC stuff, so I'll defer to you. Removed the comment at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited .ini files, used the console, and played in Steam's offline mode. I have unlocked one achievement since reconnecting Steam to online mode.

Editing .ini files will not preclude obtaining achievements.

Comment: Thanks.  In the end I reinstalled the game, loaded up a save from before I handed the dragon tablet thing in and this time I got the achievement.  So I must have messed something up that Steam didn't like, but whatever it was I'm in the dark.  At least I can retweak the ini though...